# EF Core JSON Column 'Invalid column name'

Tags: c#, json, blazor, ef-core-7.0

I have a generic update method that I'm trying to use to update an entity that I've mapped fields as JSON columns.  Reading the entity works fine, but when trying to update I receive

```
 SqlException: Invalid column name 'MORE_DATA'.
```

when attempting to save changes.  I'm lost at what the issue could be as reading the record works fine, but attempting to write the record EF doesn't know what's happening.  Something wrong with how I'm attempting to update records?

```
    public virtual async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity, AuditDetail auditDetail)
    {
        var id = entity?.ID;

        try
        {
            T existingEntity = (await _dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.ID == id)) ?? default!;

            if (existingEntity == null)
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException();
            }

                if (entity is not null)
                {
                    entity.CreatedByID = existingEntity.CreatedByID;
                    entity.CreationTS = existingEntity.CreationTS;

                    _dbContext.Attach(existingEntity);
                                            
                    var propInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
                    foreach (var item in propInfo)
                    {
                        existingEntity.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).SetValue(existingEntity, item.GetValue(entity, null), null);
                    }

                    _dbContext.Set<T>().Update(existingEntity); 

                    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                return existingEntity;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError("Update", id, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }`



    //
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
        .Entity<TableEntity>()
        .OwnsOne(obj => obj.json_field, builder =>
        {
            builder.ToJson();
            builder.OwnsOne<MORE_DATA>(obj => obj.MORE_DATA, builder =>
            {
                builder.ToJson();                       
            });
        });
    }
```

Attempting to save a record with mapped JSON data results in  error

```
 SqlException: Invalid column name 'MORE_DATA'.
```

But reading entity with JSON data works as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by *reading* the records? Deseralizing the JSON ?

Comment: Correct.  It correctly gets a record from the database, deserializes json from the json column, and maps correctly to the child object properties.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve it? I have exactly the same issue

Comment: I did not.  I resorted to manually serializing/deserializing the json to objects. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm unconvinced that you need reflection.

```
public virtual async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity, AuditDetail auditDetail)
{
    try
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            var existingEntity = (await _dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.ID == id));

            if (existingEntity == null)
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException();
            }

            entity.CreatedByID = existingEntity.CreatedByID;
            entity.CreationTS = existingEntity.CreationTS;

            _dbContext.Attach(entity); // you may not even need this. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitystate?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-entitystate-modified
            _dbContext.Set<T>().Update(entity); 

            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entity;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError("Update", id, ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: My method originally used dbcontext.Entry(existingEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity).  When I use that with a json column, the json column always updates to null.